# DrawableLeft is getting overlapped with hint using with TextInputLayout android

Tags: android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

When I try to add a drawable to left of EditText with TextInputLayout the edittext hint is getting overlapped with the drawable.

How to avoid the drawable overlapping. Without using the TextInputLayout the drawableLeft is working fine

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:drawableLef="@drawable/email" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is your EditText width is bound by the parent, which doesn't seem to be wide enough.  Either make the parent wider or make the EditText width wrap_content.

Comment: But when I using drawable with EditText with parent as LinearLayout its working fine. Problem is when I using with new design support library **TextInputLayout** I am facing this overlapping issue

Comment: Have you tried the DDMS UI hierarchy viewer?  it can be very helpful for issues like this  http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html

Comment: Looks like TextLinearLayout using LINEAR_INTERPOLATOR for it's animator, so the hint can move only along single axis.

Comment: The bug ticket for this issue has been closed as "Future Release," so I think we should see an official fix for this eventually. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175229

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175229) in the library but now in new release Version-22.2.1 this issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"` fixes the issue of the hint text over lapping the pre populated text field.